# Equation (3.6.17) in J.J. Sakurai Modern Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, angular-momentum, commutator

My question is about deriving (3.6.17) in J.J. Sakurai's book:

$$\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{L}^{2} &=\sum_{i j l m k} \varepsilon_{i j k} x_{i} p_{j} \varepsilon_{l m k} x_{l} p_{m} \\
&=\sum_{i j l m}\left(\delta_{i l} \delta_{j m}-\delta_{i m} \delta_{j l}\right) x_{i} p_{j} x_{l} p_{m} \\
&=\sum_{i j l m}\left[\delta_{i l} \delta_{j m} x_{i}\left(x_{l} p_{j}-i \hbar \delta_{j l}\right) p_{m}-\delta_{i m} \delta_{j l} x_{i} p_{j}\left(p_{m} x_{l}+i \hbar \delta_{l m}\right)\right] \\
&=\mathbf{x}^{2} \mathbf{p}^{2}-i \hbar \mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{p}-\sum_{i j l m} \delta_{i m} \delta_{j l}\left[x_{i} p_{m}\left(x_{l} p_{j}-i \hbar \delta_{j l}\right)+i \hbar \delta_{l m} x_{i} p_{j}\right] \\
&=\mathbf{x}^{2} \mathbf{p}^{2}-(\mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{p})^{2}+i \hbar \mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{p}
\end{aligned}$$

For the third equality, why the sign in front of the 2nd term and the 4th term are both negative? They both equal to $$-i \hbar \mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{p}$$
Shouldn't they take the opposite sign to cancel each other?

Comment: The calculation$$p_jx_l=x_lp_j+[p_j,\,x_l]=x_lp_j-i\hbar\delta_{jl},\,x_lp_m=p_mx_l+[x_l,\,p_m]=p_mx_l+i\hbar\delta_{lm}$$is correct since$$[x_l,\,p_m]=-[p_m,\,x_l]=-(-i\hbar\delta_{ml})=+i\hbar\delta_{lm}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two terms you mentioned weren't introduced as a zero sum. If that was the case there would be no way for the $i\hbar$, coming only from insertion of these terms, to end up in the result.

The equations are operator equations. $p_i$ and $x_i$ are operators for all $i$. The multiplication is not commutative.

The term $-i\hbar\delta_{jl}$ on the left-hand side is the commutator $[p_j,x_l]$ which has to be inserted because $p_j$ and $x_l$ switched places in the left-most term.

Similarly the right-hand term $+i\hbar\delta_{lm}$ is the commutator $[x_m,p_l]$ since $p_l$ and $x_m$ switched places in the third term. The sign is the other way around because the commutator is anti-symmetric.

In the following step of the derivation another swap of $x_l$ and $p_j$ happens on the right-hand side. (After a swap of $p_j$ and $p_m$, which *do* commute.)

That these commutator terms don't cancel is precisely the reason that the $i\hbar$ term still shows up in the result.